# Where are the parameters from Enumerable.Where method defined in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, where-clause, enumerable

I am trying to understand in more detail the use of the `Enumerable.Where` method. Even though I already understand many details including the use of lambda expression, delegates, predicates and so on, some things make no sense for me and I would appreciate any help.

First I am referring to the explanation from the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0

In the webpage above they have the following code example :

```
int[] numbers = { 0, 30, 20, 15, 90, 85, 40, 75 };

IEnumerable<int> query =
    numbers.Where((number, index) => number <= index * 10);

foreach (int number in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
/*
 This code produces the following output:

 0
 20
 15
 40
*/
```

My questions are :

1. Where are the parameters "number" and "index" defined? I understand that the "number" inside the Where is different from the "number" inside the foreach statement.
2. Why can I change the name of the parameter "number" inside the `Where` but can't change the name of "index"?
3. Why does this code produces the output 0, 20, 15, 40? I know the indexes are from 0 to 7.
4. What is the usage of the left arrow in "number <= index * 10" and what is the official name of this left arrow? (I know the right arrow is to separate input and output in a lambda expression)

Thank you for your attention and support.

Comment: Number 2 doesn't make sense. What did you try changing it to?

Comment: Change the line to "numbers.Where((myparameter, index) => myparameter <= index * 10);" and you will obtain the same results.

Comment: That [works for me](https://rextester.com/MLUY64289). Perhaps you already have something else declared as `myparameter` elsewhere in your code that's in scope at the point where you declare your lambda?

Comment: What was the exact error message you got when trying to rename index ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where are the parameters "number" and "index" defined?

They are declared when you write `(number, index) => ...`. `(number, index) =>` is short for `(int number, int index) =>`. The types can be omitted because they cam be inferred from the signature of `Where`.

The overload of `Where` that you are calling is:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource> (
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource,int,bool> predicate
);
```

`numbers` is passed to `source`, and `(number, index) => number <= index * 10` is passed to `predicate`. The types can be inferred here because from the `source` parameter, we know `TSource` is `int` (since you passed in an `int[]`), so the type of the `predicate` parameter must be `Func<int,int,bool>`.

`Func<int,int,bool>` represents a function that takes two `int` and returns a `bool`. You are supposed to give `Where` such a function. This is why you are allowed to declare the two parameters `(number, index)` - these are the parameters for the function that you are passing to `Where`. As for what the function does...

> What is the usage of the left arrow?

It is the "less than or equal to" operator. The function you are passing to `Where` returns true if `number` is less than or equal to 10 times the index of the number. You should see why only 0 (at index 0), 20 (at index 2), 15 (at index 3), and 40 (at index 6) are left in the filtered sequence. This should answer your third question too.

> Why I can change the name of the parameter "number" inside the Where but can't change the name of "index"?

You can rename just `index`:

```
(number, b) => number <= b * 10
```

or even rename both of them:

```
(a, b) => a <= b * 10
```

They are just parameter names after all. Maybe you weren't doing it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> Where are the parameters "number" and "index" defined? I understand that the "number" inside the Where is different from the "number" inside the foreach statement.

Imagine the code looks more like this:

```cs
public bool IsElementValid(int number, int index)
{
    return number <= index * 10;
}

IEnumerable<int> query = numbers.Where(IsElementValid);
```

Your code `(number, index) => number <= index * 10;` is effectively declaring an anonymous method which accepts two parameters: `number` and `index` and returns a `bool`. These are called "lambda expressions" and you can read more about them in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions).

You can pass a method here because [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__) accepts a [`Func<TElement, int, bool>` delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3?view=net-5.0). A delegate effectively allows you to store one or more methods in a variable. You can read about delegates [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/).

So now we know that a `Func` can effectively hold a method, we can digest how `Where` could work by writing our own:

```
public List<int> MyOwnWhere(int[] source, Func<int, int, bool> filter)
{
    var result = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (filter(source[i], i) == true)
        {
            result.Add(source[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Of course this isn't exactly how `Where` works, but you can get a sense of what happens under the hood re the `Func`.

I created a sample [here](https://rextester.com/MZYU5114) with some diagnostics messages to help you understand the flow.

> Why I can change the name of the parameter "number" inside the Where but can't change the name of "index"?

You can change it without breaking things. [Here](https://rextester.com/YRQZ86035) I've changed them to "bob" and "simon" and it still works.

> Why does this code produces the output 0, 20, 15, 40? I know the indexes are from 0 to 7.

Your checks are performed like this:

```
Index | Check
0     | 0 <= 0   (because 0 * 10 == 0)  result = true
1     | 30 <= 10 (because 1 * 10 == 10) result = false
2     | 20 <= 20 (because 2 * 10 == 20) result = true
3     | 15 <= 30 (because 3 * 10 == 30) result = true
4     | 90 <= 40 (because 4 * 10 == 40) result = false
5     | 85 <= 50 (because 5 * 10 == 50) result = false
6     | 40 <= 60 (because 6 * 10 == 60) result = true
7     | 75 <= 70 (because 7 * 10 == 70) result = false
```

> What is the usage of the left arrow in "number <= index * 10" and what is the official name of this left arrow? (I know the right arrow is to separe input and output in a lambda expression)

The left arrow is the mathematical symbol for ["less than"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less-than_sign). Combined with the equals, it is "less than or equal to". See [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/comparison-operators) for more.

Answer (score 2):

> Where are the parameters "number" and "index" defined? I understand that the "number" inside the Where is different from the "number" inside the foreach statement. <

That is from the enumerable extension method Where:

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,int,bool> predicate);
```

That takes takes a `Func<source,int,bool>` (a function that takes a source element from the collection, an int index and returns a bool).

> Why I can change the name of the parameter "number" inside the Where but can't change the name of "index"? <

That represents the index in the enumerable.

> Why does this code produces the output 0, 20, 15, 40? I know the indexes are from 0 to 7.

```
{ 0, 30, 20, 15, 90, 85, 40, 75 }
```

The where only produces a result ( the number from the list ) when the predicate ( number <= index * 10 ) is true

```
index 0 number  0:  0 <= 0 * 10 : true
index 1 number 30: 30 <= 1 * 10 : false
index 2 number 20: 20 <= 2 * 10 : true
index 3 number 15: 15 <= 3 * 10 : true
index 4 number 90: 90 <= 4 * 10 : false
index 5 number 85: 85 <= 5 * 10 : false
index 6 number 40: 40 <= 6 * 10 : true
index 7 number 75: 75 <= 7 * 10 : false
```

> What is the usage of the left arrow in "number <= index * 10" and what is the official name of this left arrow? (I know the right arrow is to separate input and output in a lambda expression) <

number is less than or equal to index times ten -- its a less than or equal to comparison returning a bool.